# Just can't find what I did wrong php code

Tags: php, sql, database

I am a novice trying to do the site for a non profit I volunteer with. Most of the code was gleened from You tube. Below is the code. The db name is cani the table is contact. When ever I submit is doesn't give me a success message, no data shows up in the database, and it doesn't return back to newentry.php.  My brain hurts!

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

include_once('dbh.inc.php');

$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['type']);
$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
$last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
$company = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['company']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone']);
$add1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['add1']);
$add2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['add2']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['city']);
$state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['state']);
$zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['zip']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO contact (contact_type, contact_first, contact_last,       contact_company, contact_email, contact_phone, contact_add1, contact_add2, contact_city, contact_state, contact_zip) VALUES ('$type', '$first', '$last', '$company', '$email', '$phone', '$add1', '$add2', '$city', '$state', '$zip')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location: ../newentry.php?Success!");
}else{

header("Location: ../index.html");
exit();
} 
?>
```

Grr I partially fixed it...now everything works, except nothing is showing up in the database...it is connecting, I made sure the table name is correct. It says success. But whe I open phpAdmin and open the table, it is blank.

Comment: You're still vulnerable to SQL Injections. For your safety, please use prepared statements.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments for how to get the reason for a MySQL error.

Comment: echo $sql; die(); than run the query on the database and see what is the problem

Comment: Remember your talking to a rookie...where in my code would I insert this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the variable `$_POST['submit']` exists